# How many watts of power does the man use?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, power

I was in the middle doing my homework perfectly fine until I encountered this question.

> How many watts of power does a man with a weight of 600.0 N have when he climbs a flight of stairs 3.0 m high in 5.0s?

The problem I am having is the weight part because it is my first time encountering a weight with Newtons.

**Steps I took in an attempt to find the answer:**

$P = \frac{\Delta E}{\Delta t}$   $E_g = mgh$

$P = \frac{\Delta E}{5}$  $E_g = m(9.8)(3)$

Is there any way to convert that 600.0 N into kilograms?

Comment: Weight is just a synonym for force of gravity, it's *mg*.

Comment: there is also this online http://www.convertunits.com/from/newtons/to/kilograms

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Weight or the Force of gravity = mass times acceleration of gravity
Fg=m*g
600.0N = m *$ 9.8 m/s^2 $ 
$600.0/9.8 = m $
m=61.

Comment: Can you expand on how you think this answers the question?